# jQuery - If and Else If's for marginLeft's

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, margin

i was wondering if you could help me out, i'm trying to create if based interactions on my website but sadly the code does not work and i can't think of as to why. The idea is to click a button to move it left, then when another button is clicked at it's next set position it brings it back in again.

```
if($("#featImgOne").css("marginLeft")=='0px'){
    $('#featNext').click(function(){
        $('#featImgOne').animate({marginLeft:"-960px"});
    });
    }
    else if($("#featImgOne").css("marginLeft")=='-960px'){
    $('#featPrev').click(function(){
        $('#featImgOne').animate({marginLeft:"0px"});
    });
    }
```

Just to note the first click works but the second wont, so i'm perplexed

Thanks in advance, hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the if consitions inside click handler

```
$('#featNext').click(function () {
    if ($("#featImgOne").css("marginLeft") == 0) {
        $('#featImgOne').animate({
            marginLeft: "-960px"
        });
    }
});
$('#featPrev').click(function () {
    if ($("#featImgOne").css("marginLeft") != 0) {
        $('#featImgOne').animate({
            marginLeft: "0px"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just realised how stupid i was being, too much work, too little sleep -_-

Much appreciated :)

Comment: **+1** You got the answer *first!*

Answer (score 0):

What you're expecting will not happen, because the second `click` event is never added, because at the beginning the `margin-left` is not that value.  Fix this by removing the conditional statements:

```
$('#featNext').click(function () {
    if ($("#featImgOne").css("marginLeft") == 0) {
        $('#featImgOne').animate({
            marginLeft: "-960px"
        });
    }
});
$('#featPrev').click(function () {
    if ($("#featImgOne").css("marginLeft") != 0) {
        $('#featImgOne').animate({
            marginLeft: "0px"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you also man, worked a charm, can't believe how dopey i was :')

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to add some kind of a loop. Try a while Loop.`**while**//add a condition`